# Binding setState() to a global function only affects one instance of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Note: I have edited the question after the changes I have made according to Nicholas Tower's answer.**

I have a global function which bound to a component and changes it's state.
I want to build a form builder system. There is a global function named `setLabel` which is bound to a component named `InputBox` and changes it's state. This global function is triggered via another component named `ModalPanel` which controls the editable properties on the bound component `InputBox`. I have simplified the function and component class for simplicity of this question.

Here is the global function:

```
function setLabel(postID, attributeName ){

    var text = 'example';
    if(text !== ''){

        this.setState({ [attributeName] : text});

    }
}
```

And here is the component which is bound to the `setLabel` function. Notice how `setLabel` function is passed from parent `InputBox` component to child `ModalPanel` component function as a property.

```
class InputBox extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            placeholder : '',
            maxlength: '',
            type: '',
        }

        this.setLabel = setLabel.bind(this); // Binding this to the global function.
    }

    render(){

        let elementId = "inputElement-" + this.props.idCounter;
        let mainElement = <Form.Control
                              id = {elementId}
                              type = {this.state.type}
                              placeholder = {this.state.placeholder} 
                              maxLength = {this.state.maxlength}
                          />
        return  <Row>
                    <ModalPanel
                        handleHide = {this.props.handleHide}
                        handleShow = {this.props.handleShow}
                        setLabel = {this.setLabel}
                    /> 
                </Row>
    }
}
```

Lastly, below is the `ModalPanel` component function where the `setLabel` function is triggered.

```
function ModalPanel(props){

    return(
        ......................
        ......................
        ......................
        <Button variant="primary" onClick = {() => props.setLabel()}>Save changes</Button>
        ......................
        ......................
        ......................)
}
```

`setLabel` function which is aimed to set the state of `InputBox` must be triggered when a button is clicked in the `ModalPanel` component. The problem is, there are multiple rendered `<InputBox />` components on the window and when I try to use this functionality, "the state change" only affect the first instance of `<InputBox />` component. What I want to do is that, every instance should have their own internal state and `setLabel()` function should be bound to the specific component from where it is called. So that, this function can be able to set the state of different component instances. How could I do that?

**Addition:**

Please check the link below to see a gif image showing how my system works wrong. As you can see, even though I choose the third input box element to edit it's properties (in this case, set it's placeholder text), the change is being made to the first one.

[Go to gif](https://gfycat.com/crispunfortunatechicken)

Comment: Can you expand on why you have chosen this pattern? It's highly likely that you don't need it and you are only causing yourself more trouble by trying to fix it. `setLabel = setLabel.bind(this)` - this will set the `setLabel` variable to a new bound function *which cannot be rebound*.

Comment: I will have many more components such as "CheckBoxComponent" etc. I need one global helper function to not declare same function in every different component again and again.

Comment: May not be the best answer, but have you tried to pass your element as a third argument to your function call, instead of binding it ? `function setLabel(postID, attributeName, element) {. . . element.setState(…)}` for example. Also where are you passing `propID` and `attributeName` arguments ?

Comment: @KawaLo, I am not using a propID, should I use it? Also, no I did not try your suggestion, but it does not looks like a react way.

Comment: Isn’t actually react, but generally you are right, it is not a good way to proceed. It fixed the issue for me once so I suggested it, but they are proper ways to do it (by this, I mean binding). Will try something, maybe got an idea about what the problem could be. For you function arguments, I was just wondering where you are setting `attributeName` and `propID` to update input value, as the issue may be here

Comment: I am setting it in `ModalPanel` class where the "save" button is clicked.

Comment: The solution posted below works unless something is off here. It would be easier to find out if you can create a codesandbox/stackblitz demo reproducing the problem. But the solution below [works just as expected](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kj9vyo).

Comment: `InputBox` always have only one `ModalPanel` inside?

Comment: Each `InputBox` instance has only one `ModalPanel` instance inside.

Comment: How and where are you passing the 'attributeName'?

Comment: @MonikaMangal, I am passing it at the modal side, but the problem is not caused by this parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `this.` to the beginning, as in:

```
this.setLabel = setLabel.bind(this);
```

Now you're setting a property on the instance of the InputBox. Make sure to refer to it using this.setLabel when you reference it later in the component.

Comment: It still affects only the first instance on every other instance I try. They don't even look like sharing same state, any change on other instances only affects the first instance's state.

Comment: please check my question again, I made an addition.

Answer (score 0):

Is `setLabel` acting on a specific `postID`? Is the problem that `<Button />` of every `<ModalPanel />` acting on the same `postID`? Because you aren't using `setLabel` correctly inside `<ModalPanel />`. `setLabel` takes in 2 arguments and right now your implementation isn't using any. This is your click handler.

```
onClick = {() => props.setLabel()}
```

Try `console.log`ging inside `setLabel` and see what values you're getting when you click on each button

```
function setLabel(postID, attributeName){
    console.log(postID, attributeName)
    var text = 'example';
    if(text !== ''){

    this.setState({ [attributeName] : text});

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the React components only updated from props or state changes, you need to pair the global state with a local state to update the component. See the code below in a sandbox environment.

```
let value = 0;

function updateStuff () {
  console.log("this from update", this.name);
  value++;
  this.setState({name: "Hakan " + value});
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'notchanged',
      counter: 1
    }
    this.localFunc = this.localFunc.bind(this)
    updateStuff = updateStuff.bind(this)
  }
  localFunc(){
    let {counter} = this.state;
    this.setState({counter: counter + 1});
    updateStuff();
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Test 2</div>; 
        <div>Counter: {this.state.counter}</div>
        <div>Name: {this.state.name}</div> 
        <button onClick={this.localFunc}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think, you are using React in incorrect way

The preferred way for me looks like:

1. Have a dumb/presentational InputBox which accepts `label` as a property (in props, not in state)
2. Have a smart/container component which contains state of multiple InputBoxes and passes the correct label into InputBox
3. If you are trying to implement InputBox PropertyEditor as a separate component - consider adding event bus, shared between them for example via React Context (or even use full flux/redux concept)

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your function calls after binding them or  use arrow functions !

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? OP is already using `this` which is not working. How to use arrow function here?